# error in writing a text file in python

Tags: python, file

I am writing a text file with the following code(pl in the code is a list of lists):

```
out_file = open("par.txt", 'w')
out_file.write("id\ttrans_id\ttype\tstatus\tname\ttrans_type\ttrans_status\ttrans_name\n")
for lst in pl:
    out_file(lst[0].split()[1],"\t",lst[1].split()[1],"\t",lst[2].split()[1],"\t",lst[3].split()[1],"\t",lst[4].split()[1],"\t",lst[5].split()[1],"\t",lst[6].split()[1],"\t",lst[7].split()[1])
out_file.close()
```

BUT it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    out_file(lst[0].split()[1],"\t",lst[1].split()[1],"\t",lst[2].split()[1],"\t",lst[3].split()[1],"\t",lst[4].split()[1],"\t",lst[5].split()[1],"\t",lst[6].split()[1],"\t",lst[7].split()[1])
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable
```

Comment: `out_file` is a file object, and you are calling it: `out_file(...)`... You probably want `out_file.write(...)`... Also, please familiarise yourself with the Markdown syntax used on StackOverflow (you get a preview when editing, as well as a help button), I had to extensively edit your post, since it was (very) badly formatted and not very readable, as were all the other questions you asked. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the loop to something like:

```
for lst in pl:
    out_file.write('\t'.join(x.split()(1) for x in lst))
    out_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: now it gives this error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You have a typo, `s/(1)/[1]/`.  Further, there is a (small) possibility that the OP's lists are longer than 8 elements...

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
with open("par.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("id\ttrans_id\ttype\tstatus\tname\ttrans_type\ttrans_status\ttrans_name\n")
    for lst in pl:
        f.write(("{}\t"*8).format(lst[0].split()[1],lst[1].split()[1],lst[2].split()[1],lst[3].split()[1],lst[4].split()[1],lst[5].split()[1],lst[6].split()[1],lst[7].split()[1]))
```

> It's not going to overwrite your file.You should change that *8* variable what is the length of your list, which is we dont know that list.

Example Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried but it gave this error:                                       TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple

Comment: First define a variable that takes strings in _for_ loop, then put it into _write()_

Comment: Which line gave that error can you tell me please?

Comment: Kardeşim sanırım beni anlıyosun? :D

Comment: f.write((lst[0].split()[1],"\t",lst[1].split()[1],"\t",lst[2].split()[1],"\t",lst[3].split()[1],"\t",lst[4].split()[1],"\t",lst[5].split()[1],"\t",lst[6].split()[1],"\t",lst[7].split()[1]))

Comment: now this error: TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (15 given)

Comment: I solved it, copy-paste now.I tried and its working.

Comment: now it gives this one: ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Look, We dont know what is that lists. So you should change that value _15_ before the _format()_ method fit with lenght of your list.

Comment: the list of lists is not like you have attached. there are some lists with equal length in another list

Comment: Can you try this one please. It is working, you just have to find correct number instead of _8_ because we dont know your lists.