# export data into a text file and ValueError: zero length field name in format

Tags: python, file

I am using this code to export my data into a text file(pl is a list of lists. nested lists have equal length. the columns in the file will be made from the elements of nested lists):

```
with open("par.txt", "a+") as f:
   f.write("id\ttrans_id\ttype\tstatus\tname\ttrans_type\ttrans_status\ttrans_name\n")

   for lst in pl:
       f.write(("{}\t"*16).format(lst[0].split()[1],lst[1].split()[1],lst[2].split()[1],lst[3].split()[1],lst[4].split()[1],lst[5].split()[1],lst[6].split()[1],lst[7].split()[1]))
```

But it gives this error:

> ValueError: zero length field name in format

Here is a small example of my parent list but instead of 3, I have 16 items in each list. as you see each item has 2 units which are separated by tab. the first unit would be the column names and 2nd one is corresponding value. in the text file, each nested list would be a row(2nd units of each pair)

```
pl = [[' id "ENS001" ', ' name "EGSB" ', ' Trans "TTP" '], [' id "EN02" ', ' name "EHGT" ', ' Trans "GFT" ']]
```

Comment: You have 16 repetitions of `{}` in your format string and are passing "only" 8 args to `format` -- a pretty obvious mistake (I'm sure there are others, as your insistence across Qs in writing the `lst` index and splitting repetitively, rather than, as I suggested to you elsewhere, `*(x.split()[1] for x in list)` or the like, suggests likelihood of typos &c -- but, that's the one that immediately springs to the eyes).

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an old version of Python; namely 2.6 or 3.0.  In these versions, you need to explicitly number the format fields for `str.format`:

```
f.write(("{0}\t"*16).format(
           ^
```

As with indexing, counting starts at `0`.

Note however that this is no longer necessary with modern Python.  Versions 2.7 and 3.1 or greater will automatically number the format fields for you.  For more information, see:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes

Answer (score 0):

Well I told you in this question, [error in writing a text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682012/error-in-writing-a-text-file-in-python/27682033#27682033) ; change it from *16* to *8* :

```
with open("par.txt", "a+") as f:
   f.write("id\ttrans_id\ttype\tstatus\tname\ttrans_type\ttrans_status\ttrans_name\n")

   for lst in pl:
       f.write(("{}\t"*8).format(lst[0].split()[1],lst[1].split()[1],lst[2].split()[1],lst[3].split()[1],lst[4].split()[1],lst[5].split()[1],lst[6].split()[1],lst[7].split()[1]))
```

Because we are going to put 8 items into string, as you see there are 8 items in *format()*.

> And actually, doesnt matter which length of elements, what I mean this, even this one has 100 elements in it, it will going to place by *format()* method.

```
lst[0].split()[1]
```

For example this one, doesn't matter what is the length of this element, because its still **an** element in *format()* function, so *format* function will place this.